# SQL - How do I update multiple records at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, sql-update

```sql
ALTER TABLE Store ADD TotalGoodsPrice INTEGER

CREATE VIEW V AS
SELECT Stock.Store_id,SUM(PRICE*COUNT) total FROM STOCK JOIN PRODUCT
ON STOCK.PRODUCT_CODE = PRODUCT.CODE
GROUP BY Store_id

UPDATE STORE SET STORE.TotalGoodsPrice = V.total
FROM STORE JOIN V ON v.STORE_ID = STORE.ID
```

So I have this code to update the `TotalGoodsPrice`, I want to change every record of `TotalGoodsPrice` based on the `Store.ID`, but it wont let me change. I only thought of `SELECT MAX(V.total)` but that only gives me the highest total.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want the `update ... join` syntax. The idea is to use a subquery to compute the total stock value per store from the `stock` and `product` tables, then join and update the `store` table:

```
update store se
inner join (
    select sk.store_id, sum(pt.price * sk.count) total
    from stock sk
    inner join product pt on pt.code = sk.product_code
) sk on sk.store_id = se.id
set se.totalgoodsprice = sk.total
```

I had to make a few assumptions on the table each column belongs to.

Note that storing such derived information is in general not a good idea - you then need to maintain it, which can be tedious. It might be simpler to create a view instead:

```
create view v_store as
select 
    se.*,
    (
        select sum(pt.price * sk.count)
        from stock sk
        inner join product pt on pt.code = sk.product_code
        where sk.store_id = se.id
    ) totalgoodsprice
from store se
```

Comment: Thank you so much!